# Deleting many rows from a table at once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named as person (which contains the login id of users). I was testing my application and made several test users. So right now this table has many test users and some normal users.

I want to know how can I delete all the test users?

Deleting all users one by one using `DELETE login FROM person where login = 'test_user' ;` will take long time.

PS: The test users' names do not contain test in it :/ They are just random names.

Comment: how will you identify normal and test users?

Comment: what is wrong with Pranav's answer?! maybe you should have recorded your test user's logins in a table; then it would have been easy to delete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a list of all test users?

If so, you can make a query like

```
DELETE FROM person WHERE login IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3', ...);
```

**EDIT**

In response to

> I have a list of valid users, I want to delete the rest. – [Chankey Pathak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257635/chankey-pathak)

Use

```
DELETE FROM person WHERE login NOT IN ('user1', 'user2', 'user3', ...);
```

Comment: I have a list of valid users, I want to delete the rest.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak, then you can use `NOT IN (listOfValidUsers)`

Answer (score 1):

You can take a white-list approach:

If you have a list of users you want to keep, but want to delete rows that are not in that valid list, you can use:

```
DELETE FROM person WHERE login NOT IN (<listOfValid>)
```

If you have all valid users stored in a table, you can do:

```
DELETE a FROM person a
LEFT JOIN validpersons b ON a.name = b.name
WHERE b.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM person where login like '%test%'
```

That will delete all users where their name contain `test`

Comment: The test users' names does not contain test in it :/ They are just random names.

Comment: How do you know who is a test user?